# Scala: strange performance of scala programs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: performance, scala, intellij-idea

I wanted to do some benchmarking of Scala using ProjectEuler https://projecteuler.net/ problems. Here is my solution for problem 2.

```
object Euler002 {
    def fib(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, sum: Int, end: Int): Int = {
        if (c > end) sum
        else fib(b+c, c+b+c, c+b+b+c+c, sum+c, end)
    }

    def euler002() = {
        fib(1, 1, 2, 0, 4000000)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val a = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println (euler002())
        println ("time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-a) + " millisec")
    }
}
```

What this program does is actually irrelevant. What I find strange ist that when I run this program in the console, by `typing scala Euler002.scala`, then I got the feedback `time elapsed: 1 millisec` (sometime it's 0 millisec, sometimes it's 2, but that does not matter), but when I run it in IntelliJ IDEA 14, then it says `time elapsed: 140 millisec`.

Why does it run so much slower in IntelliJ than in the console?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/tree/master/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/runner) for the Scala plugin's class runner, it seems like there is some overhead which adds those extra milliseconds.